# The reasons for segmentation fault while adding someone by sorting them into the linked list

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list

List item

```
void MovieDatabase::  addActor(const string movieTitle, const string actorFirstName, const string actorLastName, const string actorRole ){
    bool found = false;
    Movie* temp;
    for(Movie* m= headMovie; m != NULL;  m = m-> next){
            if(m-> title == movieTitle){
                found = true;
                temp = m;
                break;
            }
    }

    if(found){
            if(headCast == NULL)
                    headCast =  new Cast(actorFirstName, actorLastName, actorRole, movieTitle);
            else{
                    Cast *c =  new Cast(actorFirstName, actorLastName, actorRole, movieTitle);
                    Cast *temp = headCast;
                    for(Cast* cur = headCast; cur -> next != NULL;  cur = cur -> next){
                             if(cur ->next -> lastName <  actorLastName){
                                    temp = temp -> next;
                            }
                            else{
                                    c -> next = cur -> next;
                                    temp  -> next= c;
                                    break;
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
    else
    cout << "The movie with a " << movieTitle << "  does not exist in the database,you can not add the actor. " << endl;
    size++;
}
```

Hi everyone i edited  the code, now I'm not taking any fault. However, it does not show anything as an output. This means it does not add anyhing.
In any case, I'm sending the code for displaying.

```
void MovieDatabase:: showActors(){
    for(Cast * cur= headCast;  cur != NULL; cur = cur -> next){
         cout  << cur  -> lastName << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your edit has not fixed the bug I noted in my answer. Now you're checking cur->next in the loop rather than cur, and as that will start as NULL, you'll never enter the loop, and never add anything.

Answer (score 1):

In this bit of code:

```
for(Cast* cur = headCast; cur != NULL;  cur = cur -> next){
    if(cur ->next -> lastName <  actorLastName){
```

You are checking only that `cur != NULL`, then dereferencing `cur->next`. `cur->next` could be NULL.

`temp` and `cur` both seem to be pointing at the same node. Perhaps you intended one to be ahead of the other, in order that you have a pointer to the previous node for inserting?

Here's an (untested) implementation:

```
    Cast *c =  new Cast(actorFirstName, actorLastName, actorRole, movieTitle);
    Cast *prev = NULL; // maintain a pointer to the previous node. No previous node initially.
    Cast *cur;
    for(cur = headCast; cur != NULL;  cur = cur -> next)
    {
        if(cur -> lastName > actorLastName) break; // stop if we find a place to insert.
        prev = cur;                                // update previous pointer before looping.
    }
    if(prev != NULL)
    {
        prev -> next = c; // if there is a previous node, use 'c' as its next node.
    } else {
        headCast = c;     // otherwise 'c' is the new head node.
    }
    c -> next = cur;      // the 'current' node always goes after 'c'.
```

Comment: i'm checking only cur != NULL because i want to look at the last element also. If I just write cur-> next != NULL it does not look at the last element. Am I right?

Comment: No. You're checking *past* the last element. When `cur == lastElement`, `cur->next` will be NULL, and `cur->next->lastName` is segfaulting. You need to refactor your loop slightly such that you only look at valid nodes, and maintain a pointer to the previous node for insertion.

Comment: but i'm keeping the pointer in the previous by contolling the other element by saying -> next -> lastName. Actually this was my aim too..

Comment: No this is singly linked list not doubly.

Comment: I've added some code to my answer to try to show what I mean.

Comment: I've edited the code, there is still problem about adding but not with the segfaulting

Comment: I tried to debug and it show me that it does not enter the last else which it should be enter to add the element